# I am extracting two columns from a dataframe using pandas but one column becomes as index and then i get key error while trying to access that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip() ##found a fix for leading whitespaces
arrest_only_Y= df.loc[df['ARREST'] == 'Y']
arrest_only_Y_two_col=arrest_only_Y[["ARREST",'LOCATION DESCRIPTION','CASE#']]##running fine here 
arrest_only_Y_two_col.reset_index()
arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby = arrest_only_Y_two_col.groupby('LOCATION DESCRIPTION').count() ##and here as well ## arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby_desc=arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby.sort_values(['ARREST'],ascending = False).head()
arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby_desc.reset_index(drop = True)
arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby_desc
```

In output LOCATION DESCRIPTION becomes as index and i cant use it as a column to run this code

```
 locdesc_list = arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby_desc['LOCATION 
 DESCRIPTION'].tolist()
```

I get: `Key Error : 'LOCATION DESCRIPTION'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try this

```
df =pd.DataFrame(df,index=index,column=['A','B'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your line:

```
arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby_desc.reset_index(drop=True)
```

With:

```
arrest_only_Y_two_col_groupby_desc.reset_index(inplace=True)
```